# Uploading file as utf-8 in Python3.x

Tags: file-upload, utf-8, python-3.x

I am trying to upload a utf-8 encoded file. In Python2.x I was using something like:

`lines = filearg.file.readlines()`

In Python3.2 a get an iterator of byte streams.  I guess can do something like:

`lines = [line.decode() for line in [filearg.file.readlines()]`

I wonder whether there isn't a simpler way.  For regular files I just write:

`with open(path) as f:   ## utf-8 is the default

        lines = list[f.readlines()]`

and I get my list of utf-8 strings.

-- tsf

Comment: What do you mean by "upload"?  What's the type of `filearg`?

Comment: I am using CherryPy to run a small Web application.  Its users can upload their files: filearg is the file argument they fill in on the application page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more information (what framework are you using?), we don't know if there's a neat way to do this. But generally:

HTTP communications are bytes-based: there's not necessarily an encoding specified, and if there is, it may not be correct. So it makes sense to give you bytes and let you work out what to do with them. If you want a text file-like object, you can use [io.TextIOWrapper](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/io#io.TextIOWrapper):

```
file = io.TextIOWrapper(filearg.file, 'utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar way used in python2.x is:

```
import codecs
with codecs.open(path, encoding='utf-8') as f:
    lines = [l for l in f]
```

You can try it in python3.x